# Facebook XMPP chat API - device priority

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, xmpp, chat

I've created a Facebook app that uses the chat api using the following structure

```
Strophe.js <-- --> Punjab <-- --> Facebook XMPP
```

All works fine. My question is: Can I prevent other clients receiving messages once my app is connected?

to elaborate: if a user starts using my app to communicate he should not receive replies at the normal facebook chat ui.

Can this be done?

Comment: basically I need to send priority ... <presence from="me@myserver.tld/my_resorce">
<priority>128</priority>
</presence> , but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  You could test it using Pidgin via its [XMPP console](http://pidginmanual.wikidot.com/xmppconsole).

The [developer docs for chat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) lists supported features & has a section on limitations, which begins:

> Facebook Chat should be compatible with every XMPP client, but is not a full XMPP server. It should be thought of as a proxy into the world of Facebook Chat on www.facebook.com. As a result, it has several behaviors that differ slightly from what you would expect from a traditional XMPP service: ...

Because of this you shouldn't expect the in-browser Facebook Chat clients to behave like XMPP-compliant clients.